# How to get current loggedin username in vtiger tpl file

Tags: smarty, vtiger, vtigercrm

How i can get the current loggedin username in the header.tpl file of vtiger CRM. It should be for use inside {php} {/php} tags.

Header.tpl

```
{php} if($CURRENT_USER == 'admin') { echo "yes"; } else { echo "no"; } {/php}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$current_user_model` isn't a variable that the .tpl has in it's scope by default.

What you should do is go to the .php file for the view that you're using and add something like this:

```
$username = Users_Record_Model::getCurrentUserModel() ->get('user_name');
$viewer->assign('USERNAME', $username);
```

This passes the php variable `$username` to your tpl with the name `$USERNAME`, so now anywhere you need it in the .tpl simply use `{$USERNAME}`

Comment: Trying to add up your code in index.php file on root. Its giving me fatal error.

Comment: @junnk.. please dont copy and pste the code directly.. please check how to assign variables to tpl files from php. and after that store the variable in hidden folder and access from javascript

Answer (score 1):

You have to first assign a variable in your PHP file. Like if you want in Edit view you should define it in Edit.php file of that module or Vtiger Module. Like this using Viewer.

> $viewer->assign('CURRENT_USER_MODEL', Users_Record_Model::getCurrentUserModel());

Now you can access this variable and current username using this code from TPL file

> {$CURRENT_USER_MODEL->get('user_name')}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would help, but if you need to check what user is logged in, you can get their ID via

```
{$smarty.session.authenticated_user_id}
```

If you need the name, though, you would need to use elax's solution.